# Sorting div based on time(24 hour format) Using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to sort my divs based on Time like **07:39** > **16:00** > **21:20**

**HTML**

```
<div id="original"> <div timestamp="99" data-price="4811" data-time="16:00">16:00</div>
<div timestamp="999" data-price="4872" data-time="21:00">21:00</div>
<div timestamp="12" data-price="8586" data-time="07:00">07:00</div>
<div timestamp="11" data-price="5760" data-time="18:00">18:00</div>
<div timestamp="10" data-price="9510" data-time="05:30">05:30</div>
<div timestamp="9" data-price="9510" data-time="13:00">13:00</div>
<div timestamp="8"  data-price="4872" data-time="15:00">15:00</div>
<div timestamp="7" data-price="9510" data-time="14:00">14:00</div>
</div>
```

**JQuery/Javascript**

```
function Depart() {
var item = $("#original div").sort(function (a, b) {
    var Atime = $(a).attr("data-time");
    var Adt = new Date();
    var Adtparts = Atime.split(':');
    Adt.setHours(Adtparts[0], Adtparts[1], 0, 0);
    console.log(Adt.getTime());
    var Btime = $(b).attr("data-time");
    var Bdt = new Date();
    var Bdtparts = Btime.split(':');
    Bdt.setHours(Bdtparts[0], Bdtparts[1], 0, 0);


    if (Adt.getTime() > Bdt.getTime()) {
        return 1;
    } else if (Adt.getTime() > Bdt.getTime()) {
        return -1;
    }
    else {
      return  0;
    }
});

$("#maindiv").append(item);
```

}

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dmonstor/D6Ww5/)

This jQuery function does not work. Can you check and tell me what's wrong 
in this script? The same script works for data-price.

Comment: You are not even calling a function

Comment: Why split and use date at all? It will work just fine as a string. In what universe is this true: 16:00 > 07:39 > 21:20 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have done everything right but forgot to call the function

```
Depart();
```

And also you didn't mention the div `maindiv` in html. If you needed the sorted values inside the `#original` div then you can mention  `$("#original").append(item);` instead of `$("#maindiv").append(item);`

See the working demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/D6Ww5/5/)

Comment: @mplungjan: Any pblm with my answer?

Answer (score 2):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4UZeg/)

Add maindiv in html & call Depart in jquery.

```
<div id="maindiv"></div>

Depart();
```

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to call `Depart();` function

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    Depart();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code without the unnecessary date manipulation.
This works because your time is padded with 0s

[<kbd>**Live demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/AUEg4/)

```
function Depart() {
  var item = $("#original div").sort(function (a, b) {
    var Atime = $(a).attr("data-time");
    var Btime = $(b).attr("data-time");
    if (Atime > Btime) return 1;
    if (Atime < Btime) return -1;
    return  0;
  });
  $("#maindiv").append(item); // or $("#original").append(item); 
}
Depart(); // execute
```

I guess you want to execute the depart on load and on click of something:

```
$(function() {
  $("#depart").on("click",function() {
    Depart();
  }).click(); // assign onload and click it right away
});
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I was trying to understand your code. But, was taking too much of time. So, I written something mine. Hope you won't mind.

Well, I have not treated the thing as `Date()` object, string works fine for this. So, what I have done is:

```
function Depart() {
    var elms = $("[data-time]", "#original"),
        times = [],
        newTime = [],
        html = $("<div />");

    // Getting Time
    elms.each(function(){
        times.push($(this).data("time").replace(":", ""));
    });

    times.sort(); // Sorting
    //times.reverse(); // If required

    // Resetting format
    $.each(times, function(c, obj){
        newTime.push(obj.substr(0,2) + ":" + obj.substr(2,4));
    });

    // Creating new HTML
    $.each(newTime, function(c, obj){
        elms.each(function(){
            if($(this).data("time") == obj){
                html.append($(this));
            }
        });
    });

    // Setting the HTML
    $("#original").html(html);
}

Depart();
```

Here is the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ashishanexpert/D6Ww5/7/

I wish, this helps you!

Comment: Because this is so much easier to understand than the 7 lines necessary?

Comment: @mplungjan: if I remove the line breaks/white spaces and comments, it will be even less lines of code than the original one.

Comment: But not more understandable - please see my answer for what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
Depart();});
```